# Kernel of a bilinear map and tensor product specificially

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

I am cementing my understanding of tensors and a book I am reading handwaves and simply says "of course we may denote $0\otimes 0$ as the $0$ of $U\otimes V$"

I have proved that the kernel is larger than that, but the proof is a little bit "backwards" - I'd like someone to tell me if I can write it in a more 'from definitions' way.

Let $f$ be a bilinear map on $U\times V$ to $W$

First off: $\text{Ker}(f)=\{(u,v)\in U\times V|f(u,v)=0\}$

I'd like a proof that says "Let $(u,v)\in\text{Ker}(f)$" and shows what is required. What I have is:

- $\forall u\in U[0u=0]$
  So using this logic $\forall (u,v)\in U\times V[0f(u,v)=0]$
  Then $0f(u,v)=f(0,v)=f(0,u)=0$
  So $\text{Ker}(f)\subseteq\{(u,v)\in U\times V|u=0\vee v=0\}$

I have proved that $[u=0\vee v=0]\implies f(u,v)=0$, I would like a "cleaner" proof of this.

---

The second question I have is I'd like prove that $u\otimes v=0\iff[u=0\vee v=0]$ and I'm not sure how I'd go about doing that.

If you can only answer the first question that's fine! Having a nicer proof will be instrumental in tackling the second part.

Comment: What are your "definitions"?  Is it simply something like $(a+b)\otimes c = a\otimes c + b \otimes c$?  Do you know about the definition via universal property?

Comment: Are you saying that, by definition,
$$
u \otimes v = 0 \iff f(u,v) = 0 \text{ for every bilinear } f?
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I want a "clean" proof for: Given ANY bilinear map $f$ that $[u=0\vee v=0]\implies f(u,v)=0$. That's the first part. The second part is I want to make this and $\iff$ when $f=\otimes$ (the tensor product). I know the tensor product as ... well what you wrote, a sort of "non-commmutative multiplication" if you will. However I am edging towards http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Notes:ToMond#Question - I don't know it this way yet. (It's actually why I'm doing this. I'm seeking to prove there's something more at play, work so far is in that link)

Comment: Your proof is 3 lines long, you can't get much cleaner than that.  The definition given on that page for the tensor product is usually called the "universal property" definition, for future reference.

Comment: @AlecTeal What's wrong with the proof for the first part? It's basically one line's worth of reasoning, and so pretty efficient. For the second proof I suppose you could contract both sides of $u \otimes v = 0$ with a suitable vector in the dual space.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I've just thought of a cleaner version, starting with "let $u,v$ be given with one or both $=0$ (in their own vector space)" then showing it belongs to the kernel. Which proves that part.

Comment: @Travis see above. My three lines are what I'd call "workings"

Comment: What you want to show for the other implication is that if $u \neq 0$ and $v \neq 0$, then there **exists** a bilinear map such that $f(u,v) \neq 0$.

Comment: Then again, you've never said what $U,V$ are.  Are these simply vector spaces?

Comment: Sorry @Omnomnomnom - I've been messing with this for so long now I assumed everyone just knew. U, V and W are vector spaces of the same field.

Comment: No problem, just checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Proof of the second part:**

We assume that both $U$ and $V$ contain a non-zero vector.

Suppose that $u$ and $v$ are non-zero.  We may extend each to a basis of $U$ and $V$ respectively.  That is, we now have the bases
$\{u = u_1,u_2,\dots\}$ and $\{v = v_1,v_2,\dots\}$ of $U$ and $V$.  We define the bilinear map
$$
f_{u,v}:\left(\sum_{i \in I} a_i u_i,\sum_{j \in J} b_j v_j\right) \mapsto a_1b_1
$$
Since $f_{u,v}(u,v) \neq 0$, we may conclude $u \otimes v \neq 0$.

Comment: I fear looking silly, but I shall ask anyway. Where did you pull your $a_i$s and $b_i$s from. (Would you write "Let ....." - I'm looking for clean proofs remember) and as for how it works. Am I correct in saying the page I linked above is actually entirely correct, and I have found the "characteristic property" of tensor products, by finding a bilinear map that is non zero, we /necessarily/  have the tensor being non-zero. I like that. You've answered the question, for that I am grateful, but could I push it and ask for an outline of an alternate proof, not using the universal property?

Comment: We can find (unique) such scalars $a_i$ and $b_j$ by the definition of a basis.  It is a theorem that every vector space has a basis.

Comment: Note that (again, by the definition of a basis) all but finitely many $a_i$ and $b_j$ are zero (which is important if $U$ and $V$ are infinite dimensional).

Comment: But surely those scalars are $a_1=1$ and $a_i=0$ otherwise "" for $b_i$. Oh I see what you've done now! My final question (thanks for indulging me) is: what happens in infinite dimensional vector spaces. I am not comfortable with extending to a basis there. I'll also investigate why you didn't choose a canonical one (an $f$ independent of basis)

Comment: In infinite dimensional spaces, we want to avoid bases that require infinite sums, since we might not have a topology by which infinite sums may "converge". So, a basis is by definition a set where we may take the linear combination of a *finite* subset of the basis to represent any vector.  The fact that we can always do this is usually proven using (and is equivalent to) Zorn's lemma, which is in turn equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Comment: Remember: it's not that I've chosen my basis to depend on $f$, it's that I've defined $f$ using my basis.

Comment: The page you've linked has a correct definition of tensor products via universal properties.  And yes, $\tilde f$ has to be unique.

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't quite get (infinite dimensional vec. spaces in general) but I can see how choosing a basis such that $u\in U$ has coordinates $(1,0,0,\cdots)$ sidesteps that. Which is good enough for me. Thanks, really. Much appreciated.

Comment: In retrospect, Fallen Apart's approach seems a bit more sensible.  That also uses the universal property, and rather than constructing a basis, we simply take for granted that if $v \neq 0$, there is a linear $f:V \to \Bbb F$ with $f(v) \neq 0$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But still i had to use Axiom of Choice when fixing a map $f.$ It is hidden, but still.

Comment: I thought about giving @FallenApart the tick (the rep would make more of a dent with him anyway) but I find this to be much more accessible. You also read my link and answered the questions. It wasn't an easy choice!

Comment: It wasn't the point of my comment. I just wanted to notice that i also used Axiom of Choice to define $f.$ BTW I can live without 15 points. Hardly, but I think I can manage that.

Comment: @AlecTeal [here wiki confirms your take on tensor products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Universal_property).

Comment: @FallenApart yes, I appreciate it.  I noticed, but I think you covered it up in a nicer way.

Comment: I've got one more question I'd like to pester you with please. Suppose that we have two bilinear maps from $U\times V$ to $X$ and another to $Y$. I know there are linear maps from $U\otimes V$ to $X$ and $U\otimes V$ to $Y$, but is there a map from $X$ to $Y$ or $Y$ to $X$? in the finite dimensional case (so $U\times V$ is finite dimensional) I have concluded "there must be" but in general? Also this suggests a lattice structure with various subspaces and whatnot, I'm interested to find out more.

Comment: There's a linear map between any two vector spaces.  I don't know how you would make a map using the bilinear maps, though.  I guess you could if you had something from $X \to U \otimes V$ or $Y \to U \otimes V$.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the first thing you want to proof (in a "clean" way) is the following claim:

> Let $U,V,W$ be vector spaces and $f:U\times V\rightarrow W$ be billinear. For every $u\in U$ and $v\in V$  $f(u,0_V)=f(0_U,v)=0$

This is true for $$f(0_U,v)=f(0\cdot 0_U,v)=0 \cdot f(0_U,v)=0=0\cdot f(u,0_V)=f(u,0\cdot0_V)=f(u,0_V)$$

The above is the sufficient condition for being in the kernel as for the necessary one we have:

> Let $U,W$ be vector spaces. For every $u\in U$ and $v\in V$
> $$u\otimes v=0_{U\otimes V}\implies \text{$u$ or $v$ equals 0 in its own space.}$$

Proof:

Assume that $u\otimes v=0_{U\otimes V}.$
If $u\neq 0_U,$ then we have a linear map $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ for example dot product in U,such that $f(u)$ is a unit and let $g:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary linear map. Consider now bilinear map $\phi:U\times V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by formula
$$\phi(x,y)=f(x)\cdot g(y)$$
By property of tensor product it gives rise to linear map $h:U\otimes V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$h(x\otimes y)=f(x)\cdot g(y).$$
Since $u\otimes v=0_{U\otimes V}$ we get that
$$0=h(u\otimes v)=f(u)\cdot g(v)\leadsto g(v)=0.$$
We are now in the situation that for every linear map $g:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $g(v)=0$ holds. Hence $v=0_V.$(take norm if you like)

Similarly if $v\neq0_V,$ then $u=0_U.$
$\square$

Comment: Could I have a picture of the pages please, I'm looking up the book now but I do not have it

Comment: @Alec_Teal Ok. I will edit the answer. Wait a second.

Comment: Everything okay?

Comment: $ Alec_Teal. No, I've done proof instead.